# Fetching has many relationship data Laravel and using avg function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Laravel 5 with vue js. Basically i am fetching data using axios and trying to display on the webpage using vue js v-for directive.
i have tables in database like this:

`ratings Table`

`id` `review_id` `rating`

Then i have a

`reviews table`

`id` `review`

They have one to many relationship between. so here in my `Review` Model i have method

```
 public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Rating')
            ->selectRaw('review_id,AVG(rating) AS average_rating')
            ->groupBy('review_id');
    }
```

so here i want to fetch list of reviews with their average ratings. so in my controller i am doing this:

```
  public function getAllReviews(Request $request)
    {
        $reviews = Review::with('ratings')->get();

        return $reviews;
    }
```

So i am getting result but the problem is every review doesnt have ratings record so it is returning null? maybe... 
when i try to render in vue template it throws an error `undefined` because in our collection some reviews do not have ratings.

Now my question is: Can i do something like if there is no record in the ratings for a particular review is it possible to add an array with value 0?? so in my frontend it wont see as undefined.

I hope i am successful to explain i am trying.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a proper use of a relationship, but you definitely won't want hasMany if you're trying to aggregate.

Comment: So how can I get average rating for each review and that also in a single result??)

Comment: Single result would mean you want to use hasOne.  However, I can't verify how well aggregation functions work with relationships.  Eloquent relationships aren't really designed for that.

Comment: It's giving me expected result. But problem is when there is no rating for a particular then it is returning empty array. See suppose I have some ratings for review id 1 . As I'm using eager loading so it gives me result like this. A collection of reviews and inside of every collection there is an array called ratings that we have mentioned while eager loading. In this ratings array there are keys review_id and average_rating (this also we have mentioned while defining relationship. But when there is no ratings this ratings array is empty which I don't want.

Comment: I want if there is no ratings then my ratings array should return key average_rating and value 0.

Comment: But now if there is no ratings it returns empty array without keys and values and this creating problem in my Vue js code)

Comment: So could we check if no ratings then manually put array with key average_ratings with value 0??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it this way:

```
public function getAllReviews(Request $request)
{
    $reviews = Review::selectRaw('*, IFNULL((SELECT AVG(rating) FROM ratings where ratings.review_id = reviews.id), 0) as avg_rating')->get();

    return $reviews;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the basic relationship and a modified `withCount()`:

```
public function ratings() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
}

$reviews = Review::withCount(['ratings as average_rating' => function($query) {
    $query->select(DB::raw('coalesce(avg(rating),0)'));
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Don't you think coalesce will return first record which is not null. Where I want to append a record with value 0 if relationship not exist. I know my requirement is strange but this is what I need to get.

Comment: Can you work with a relationship that returns a single instance instead of a collection? I can give you a (hacky) solution for that. You would use it like this: `$review->rating->average_rating`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showProduct($id)
    {   

        $data = Product::where('category_id',$id)
                ->selectRaw('*, IFNULL((SELECT AVG(value) FROM ratings where ratings.product_id = products.id), 0) as avg_rating')
                ->get();

        return view('ecommerce.web.productsOfcategory',compact('data'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$avgQuery = "IFNULL((SELECT AVG(ratings.rating) FROM ratings WHERE ratings.review_id = reviews.id),'No Ratings') as avg_rating";

$reviews = Review::query()->selectRaw("reviews.*, $avgQuery")->get();

//SQL Query
$sqlQuery = "select reviews.*, IFNULL((SELECT AVG(ratings.rating) FROM ratings where ratings.review_id= ratings.id), 'No ratings') as avg_rating FROM reviews";
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding an answer to an older question with an accepted answer it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Code only answers can generally be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work.